# Given a set of numbers $x_i$, find $x_c$ that is gives smallest distance variance

Tags: calculus

**Note**

Please add/modify tags as appropriate. Not sure what tags to use.

**Background**

While writing a touch UI for a mobile app, I stumbled across a problem I wanted to solve, which is to derive the **centerpoint** (defined later in the problem) of a non-zero number of inputs at $(x_1, y_1), ... (x_n, y_n)$.

Although I ultimately settled for a simpler algorithm, I'm still interested in seeing a solution to the problem. Below is the 1-dimensional version of the problem.

**The Problem**

Given a set of n points 
*$$\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}, x_i \in \Bbb{R}$$*

Define a **variable point** $x$ such that the **distance** from the $i^{th}$ point is
$$d_i = |x_i - x|$$

So, the set of distance values for all n points is
$$\{d_1, d_2, ..., d_n\} = \{|x_1 - x|, |x_2 - x|, ..., |x_n - x|\}$$

The average distance is:
$$d_{avg} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i{d_i}$$

The variance is:
$$ \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i(d_i - d_{avg})^2$$

Solve generally for the **centerpoint** $x_c$, defined as the value of $x$ that gives the smallest $\sigma^2$. Approximate solutions are welcome too.

**Example 1:**

Given the set $\{0, 8, 8\}$, try $x_c = 4$. Then:

$d_{set} = \{|0-4|, |8-4|, |8-4|\} = \{4, 4, 4\} $

$\implies d_{avg} = 4$

$\implies \sigma^2 = 0$

**Example 2:** $\{0, 4, 8\} \implies x_c = 4, \sigma^2 = 16$

**Example 3:** $\{0, 4, 12\} \implies x_c \approx 5.3, \sigma^2 \approx 37.3$

Comment: Since, as noted in example 1, duplicate values don't necessarily influence the centerpoint, it might make more sense to solve this algorithmically (sort values ascending, calculate neighbour proximity, ...) than with a "traditional" function

Comment: Is this the median? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

Comment: Doesn't look like a median calculation to me. Going with the examples 1 thru 3, the medians would be 8, 4, and 4, respectively. But the $x_c$ values are 4, 4, and 5.3, respectively.

Comment: To check: d_set = {abs(c-x_1), abs(c-x_2), ...}. d_avg = the average of the elements of d_set. ^2 = the average of the squares of the differences between the elements of d_set and d_average. (I don't understand why d_avg has a 1/n term, but ^2 has a 1/(n-1) term, or why d_avg ignores duplicate elements.)

Comment: My mistake with the (n-1) term; question is corrected. $d_{avg}$ does not ignore duplicate elements, but duplicate elements do not necessarily influence the answer. E.g. {0, 8} and {0, 8, 8} both give the solution $x_c$ = 4.